# Magento2 Product details page not displaying images after installing s3

Tags: magento2, s3

Magento2 Product images not getting displayed on Product details page

I used following extension for S3 Bucket

> https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3/wiki/Installation

On details page error image is getting Forbidden

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
> (Forbidden)
>
> https://s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/monogramtestbed/catalog/product/cache/648bd0b6614023c7d4802a253ddbf578/c/r/cream_2_.jpg

Comment: this could be an issue with .htaccess file try to delte that from room and that add a new a new file by downloading it from here https://gist.github.com/Jonathonbyrd/3afd9f221b3b83dc6be9